# How can I get all Magento Product Brands

Tags: magento

How do I get an array or object containing all of the product brands without going through the full collection of products.

The idea is to create a dynamic brand page with links back to each of the brands.

So the code afterwords would be something like:

```
<ul>
<?foreach ($brands as $brand):?>
<li>
<a href="<?=$helper->getBrandUrl($brand)?>"><?=$helper->getBrandName($brand)?></a>
</li>
<?endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using separate Magento extension? I am not aware of Magento having brand functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my magento brand is attribute number 66 and I can have all brand with this request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM eav_attribute_option o, eav_attribute_option_value v
WHERE attribute_id = '66'
AND o.option_id = v.option_id
```

But if you need in an OOP way use this instead :

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load(66);
$attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();  ?>
            <?php foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
            if ($option['value']) echo $option['value']." > ".$option['label']."<br/>";
            } ?>
```

Comment: Works well, Ty
For reference you can test with this in a controller:
    function indexAction(){
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load(66);
        $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        foreach($attributeOptions as $option){
            if($option['value']) echo $option['label']."<br>";
        }

    }

Comment: Don't put "echo" instruction in a Controller, if you're in a controller context, you should create a function in the block to return $attributeOption, load a layout and add the block in the controller, and call the function in the template to get and perform the array of options.